# For Loop Being Skipped Over

Tags: excel, vba

I have not been able to figure out why the For Loop block (with two for loops) is being skipped over by the code. I know it's being skipped bc a message box is being tripped further down in the code. Any thoughts?

```
Dim OL As Outlook.Application
Dim myitem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim PicPath As String
Dim x, y As Integer
Dim Name As Name
Dim cell, rng1 As Range


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Request type check
If (Sheet1.NewResource.Value = False) And (Sheet1.Modification.Value = False) Then
    MsgBox "Please select a Request Type of your request and complete the other mandatory fields"
    GoTo cont
End If

'checking New Resource Entry mandatory fields
If Sheet1.NewResource.Value = True Then

    If (Sheet1.NewPOnobx.Value = False) And (Sheet1.NewPOyesbx.Value = False) Then
        MsgBox "Please fill the missing mandatory fields"
        GoTo cont
    End If

    If (Sheet1.POyesbx.Value = False) And (Sheet1.POnobx.Value = False) Then
        MsgBox "Please fill the missing mandatory fields"
        GoTo cont
    End If

    If (Sheet1.POnobx.Value = True) And (Sheet1.SOWtxt.Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Please select a copy of the Signed Agreement"
        GoTo cont
    End If

    For Each Name In ActiveWorkbook.Names 'each named range in gateway fields
        If (Name = "C_LN") Or (Name = "C_FN") Or (Name = "C_SD") Or (Name =  "C_ED") Or (Name = "C_O") Or (Name = "C_D") Or (Name = "C_OF") Or (Name = "C_C") Or (Name = "C_M") Or _
        (Name = "C_R") Or (Name = "C_PT") Or (Name = "C_V") Or (Name = "C_SAR") Or (Name = "C_BAR") Or (Name = "C_SR") Or (Name = "C_SS") Or (Name = "C_PO") Then 'all gateway field names
            x = 0
            For Each cell In Name 'cell in the named range
                If cell.Value = "" Then 'looking for blank mandatory fields
                    If (cell.Name = "LN_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "FN_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "SD_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "ED_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "O_Cmt") Or _
                    (cell.Name = "D_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "OF_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "C_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "M_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "R_Cmt") Or _
                    (cell.Name = "PT_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "V_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "SAR_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "BAR_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "SR_Cmt") Or _
                    (cell.Name = "SS_Cmt") Or (cell.Name = "PO_Cmt") Then
                        GoTo skip1
                    Else
                        x = x + 1 '+1 for a blank mandatory field
                    End If
                End If
skip1:
            Next cell

                If x > 0 Then 'flag the missing info
                    MsgBox "Please fill the missing mandatory fields"
                    GoTo cont
                End If

            End If
        Next Name

End If
```

Comment: `I know it's being skipped bc a message box` - that is no good, please use the debugger. The key is `F8`.

Comment: What does the GoTo Skip1 accomplish?  Try commenting that out and see if things work better.  (Having a blank THEN action before the ELSE is legal.)  GoTo statements can mess things up, and this one serves no obvious purpose.  Definitely use the debugger -- put the red Stop Sign in the left column & then F8 t step through your code to see what's happening.

Comment: the purpose for the Skip1 is to skip the  x variable counter and continue to the next cell.

Comment: my bigger issue is that the code isn't even get picked up...i have done the debugger and put a stop after For Each Name In ActiveWorkbook.Names and it's not being stopped there

Comment: Then put a breakpoint above there and see why the condition to enter the loop is not being met. (Set a breakpoint at `If Sheet1.NewResource.Value = True Then` and step through the code from there to see what's happening. We can't do that for you, because we don't have the spreadsheet to use to do so.)

Comment: Not on my computer so can't check, but doesn't the .name give you a string of the address... I.e. Use Name.RefersToRange (or something) gives the actual range object containing cells

Comment: The ELSE statement will cause the x=x+1 statement to be skipped over anyway when the IF condition evaluates as TRUE.  The GoTo is unnecessary.  Concur that Name isn't what you want to call your variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the `Name` in the for loop gives something like `=Sheet1!$G$2:$G$5` ... this doesn't match your `C_R` or whatever. I need to use `Name.Name` to get that. And then to get the range of cells for the name, I need to use `Name.RefersToRange`.

Also, to make your `If` list easier to manage, you could use `Select Case` instead:

```
  Select Case Name.Name
    Case "C_LN", "C_FN", "C_SD",  "C_ED", "C_O", "C_D", "C_OF", "C_C", "C_M", "C_R", "C_PT", "C_V", "C_SAR", "C_BAR", "C_SR", "C_SS", "C_PO"
      For Each cell In Name.RefersToRange
        Debug.Print cell.Address
      Next cell
    Case Else
      Debug.Print "Other Name"
  End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use name it is a reserved word (you can rename files with Name File1 as File2).

Change the variable name to MyName or something similar then if you continue to experience the issue, put a stop on the code and evaluate the loop manually in the debug wind (CTRL-G) by typing ?activeworkbook.Names.Count and pressing enter (don't forget the ?) and see if you have a number above zero.

Comment: `Name` is a context-dependent keyword. It is only a keyword in the `Name ... As ...` clause and not a keyword anywhere else. It is okay to have a variable named `Name`. You can even do `Name Name As Name`.